# Can someone translate this Chop?

Tags: translation

My parents got me this chop when they went to China but I have no idea what it says... can someone translate? (Sorry for the awful stamping... I couldn’t get it to stamp super clear.) [image]

Comment: Omg thank you so much! That just made it so much more special :)

Comment: I voted to close this because we had a policy a while back that only difficult to parse (cursive calligraphy, seals) identification requests would be allowed.

Comment: I didn't vote to close this question at once was because some non-Chinese speakers might wrongly think the top and bottom symbols were Chinese too. Anyway, there is no need for any additional answer now

Comment: That policy is silly. For people who know nothing about hanzi, can they tell whether the writing is cursive?

Comment: @joehua Chinese SE is the only language stack which allows effortless translation requests. Other stacks have an outright ban. To keep questions about character identification and translation even mildly beneficial, we have to limit them to something that your average native speaker has trouble with, so they may also be able to learn something. It doesn’t matter if the asker isn’t aware of what is or isn’t cursive; the average new question asker across all stacks isn’t aware of the rules in that stack, nobody makes excuses for them if they violate some rule and their questions get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The text is 我爱你 (simplified Chinese), meaning "I love you". The top of the chop is a symbol of sun-ray and the bottom seems like either cloud or sea wave ( it does look like the infinity symbol, but if that is the case, there should only be one)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The top is sunset(or sunrise?) picture.

The middle is "我愛你"  (I love you)

The bottom is infinity  => ∞ ∞

Comment: sun like [this](https://tw.pixtastock.com/illustration/39940136)

Comment: I posted my answer before there was an answer to this post (I had this page open without refresh it) , I didn't copy 高鵬翔\'s answer. Does anyone think we can't independently come up with the same answer given we are both native Chinese users? It took me a few minutes to copy and edit the picture and someone has answered the question in the meantime is not a reason to accuse me of plagiarism. As for the  bottom symbol, I do not agree it is infinity (I think it is a cloud or sea wave),   therefore I added the comment

Comment: I would not have posted my answer if I've seen an acceptable answer. Most of the time my answer seems similar to an earlier posted answer is the same reason as this time

Comment: In fact it is more accurate to say that the Chinese characters are 我爱你 rather than 我愛你, because the picture contains the latter simplified characters rather than the former traditional characters. This difference is also not trivial because it shows the fact that the product was bought in Mainland China, and not in Taiwan or Hong Kong SAR. And I also don't think the forms at the bottom are the infinity symbol, but rather some cloud or sea wave, as suggested by Tang Ho.

Comment: @starckman I don't think we're going to force people to use any particular character standard when they attempt to transcribe a picture, otherwise the majority of attempts to transcribe e.g. seal characters will be wrong, because hardly anyone (even native speakers) will pay attention to exact character components or character variants even if they can read seals.